# Sign "$" in shell command

Tags: shell, sh

Please, explain why needed `"$"` in this command. OC FreeBSD, `/bin/sh`

`rm $(ls|grep '.*\.gz')`

Without `"$"` this command doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is similar to "why is there a 'c' in the word 'cat'?"  If you remove the 'c', you get a different word.  Similarly, if you remove the '$', you get a different command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about the `$()`. From [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> The POSIX $() form of command substitution is implemented (see Command
>   Substitution), and preferred to the Bourne shell’s `` (which is also
>   implemented for backwards compatibility).

So the `rm $(ls|grep '.*\.gz')` expression is doing `rm` to the output of the execution of `ls|grep '.*\.gz'`.

#### Example

```
$ date "+%F %T %Z"
2013-10-24 10:49:23 CEST
$ d=$(date "+%F %T %Z")
$ echo "$d"
2013-10-24 10:49:26 CEST
```

Comment: @Andry It's the same as using `backtics`, however using `$()` is favoured due to nesting issues with backtics. One very important thing about `backtics` and `$()` is that they `fork`. Doing `date` gets executed in the same shell whereas `$(date)` forks a subshell and executes `date`.

Comment: @Jite But with `${date}` it will executed in current shell? Right?

Comment: @Andry, `${date}` will print the variable `$date`. `$()` is for command execution, while `${}` is for shell parameter expansion.